# Magento 1.9 Get price from catalog price rule to a SKU programmatically

Tags: magento-1.9, catalog-price-rules, special-price

In Magento, we can use `$product->getSpecialPrice()` to get the discount price which is set under product view.

Is there a way to get the discount price for a SKU from Catalog Price Rule programmatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution.

```
Mage::getModel('catalogrule/rule')->calcProductPriceRule($product,$product->getPrice());
```